# Loop through array in mysql Stored procs

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I need to dynamically alter set of tables
Currently i can alter only one using below SP.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_version_to_actor;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE add_version_to_actor (IN table_name VARCHAR(40) ) 
BEGIN
DECLARE colName TEXT;
SELECT column_name INTO colName
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'database_name'
    AND table_name = table_name
AND column_name = 'column';

IF colName is null THEN 
    Alter Table database_name.table_name ADD `sequence` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL;
END IF; 
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL add_version_to_actor('table1');

DROP PROCEDURE add_version_to_actor;
```

Currently 'table1' is a single parameter. I need to pass multiple table names as string like this `CALL add_version_to_actor('table1','table2');`and loop through all of them.How can this be achieved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you use while loop in sql by creating one more new sp that will pass table name one by one to another sp

Comment: @cracker thats the problem, creating while loop on comma separated values. can you give me some code for it.

Comment: try this => http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/584680/Using-comma-separated-value-parameter-strings-in-S